How can i update data for the same row after using the Query and importrange function in google sheet?
I have 2 Spreadsheets

Spreadsheets 1 has my main Data E.g. client Name, email, Contact Number, Payment done

SpreadSheet 1

spreadsheet 2 where I'm importing the data from Spreadsheet 1 using query and importrange and I marked yes where call audit done for client.

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ac015ADMUfAJr45zopPoFxdMpUOPbsqcikKXio10DFg", "Sheet1!A2:D"), "Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col4 = 'Completed'")

SpreadSheet 2
The problem here is when updating the spreadsheet let's take an example of row 1 where the current data is from a spreadsheet is for Name - Abs and I marked yes for Name ABC. But when I make changes in Spreadsheet 1 i.e. row number 4 client Name "SPS" marked payment completed.
Updated spreadsheet 1
Then my spreadsheet showed the changes but where I marked yes for the client Name in spreadsheet 2 it's not moving along with for which I marked yes for the client name. My Yes it is there as it is.
Changes in spreadSheet 2
I want it to move along with the same client name for which I marked yes
result which i want

What condition and formula did you use? kindly update your question.

Can you please add the condition? I understand that you want to get the data from the first sheet where payment is completed on the second sheet and you are manually adding "Yes" in the second sheet. So you want if payment type gets changes audit also gets to change?

I'm creating sheet 2 for another person who is adding "yes" after the call audit. I don't want it automatically. if i make changes in sheet 1 it is showing in sheet 2. That's not my concern. my concern is when I make changes in sheet 1. 3rd person who is updating yes in E4 for A4 client. I want it to move "yes" E4 along with  A4. if my A4 moves to A5 after updation in sheet1 then my E4 "yes" also moves to E5 as well.  I hope you are getting my point. Please refer the image for result.  @SourabhD.

While there maybe odd workarounds to deal with this scenario but as a general matter of fact, you cannot automatically link a dynamic range (which you are importing from Sheet 1) & the static range you have in Sheet 2 since sheets is not intended to be a relational database of sorts! I'd suggest to lookout/seek help for a [google-apps-script] that copy-pastes the sheet1 data to sheet2 based on a trigger; this way it doesnt matter what dynamic changes are happening within sheet1, it remains static in Sheet2 once its pasted off!
